# CIFilter applied to an image not working - swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, cifilter

I am trying to apply a CIFilter to an image that is already displayed in my imageView in my single view application but it does not appear to have applied the filter.  Please can someone advise?  My input image appear exactly the same.

SWIFT:

```
let filter = CIFilter.init(name: "CIHueAdjust")
let context = CIContext()
var extent: CGRect!
var scaleFactor: CGFloat!

@IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let ciImage = CIImage.init(image: img.image!)

    filter?.setDefaults()
    filter?.setValue(ciImage, forKeyPath: kCIInputImageKey)
    let result = filter?.outputImage
    print("result: \(result)")

    var image = UIImage.init(cgImage: context.createCGImage(result!, from: result!.extent)!)
    img.image = image


    img.image = image
}
```

CONSOLE:

```
 result: Optional(<CIImage: 0x1c001a7a0 extent [0 0 2016 1512]>
 affine [1 0 0 -1 0 1512] extent=[0 0 2016 1512] opaque
colormatch "sRGB IEC61966-2.1"_to_workingspace extent=[0 0 2016 1512] opaque
  IOSurface 0x1c401a780(169) seed:1 YCC420f 601 alpha_one extent=[0 0 2016 1512] opaque
```

Comment: More detail is needed for me to help you... namely, what is happening? The likeliest place is in your call to `outputImage`, where it may be returning `nil`. I'd suggest two things. (1) Break that line of code into *at least* three separate lines - call to `outputImage`, `context.createCGImage`, and `UIImage.init`. (2) Put some breakpoints in and see what's happening.

Comment: @dfd The output image looks exactly the same as my input image.  The filter appears to not have been applied.  That is my issue

Comment: Now that I know the issue, my first guess would be that you have no issue - rather, you are just setting the defaults which result in an unchanged image. It looks like this filter has a single attribute, `inputAngle` with a min value of 0 and a max value of 1. Since zero is the default, try setting this attribute to 1. Pass it as a `Float`.

Comment: @dfd sorry, how would i do that.  When i type in 'filter.' there appears to be no option to enter 'inputAngle' as an autocomplete option...could you put this into code for me as an answer?

Comment: Just like you set the value for `inputImage` (which is the actual string value of `kCIInputImageKey`) do it for the angle: `filter?.setValue(Float(1), forKey: "inputAngle")`. Also, I just noticed this - I'm sure `forKeyPath:` *was* the correct syntax back in Swift 2, maybe even Swift 3, but if you're using Swift 4 it's `forKey:`. That should result in a build error though.

Comment: Last comment. If you want to know virtually anything about available CIFilters (including attribute names and values, how images look after applying one) I always recommend an **iPad only** GitHub project called Filterpedia. The original, written in Swift 2 and one updated to Swift 4 are here: https://github.com/FlexMonkey/Filterpedia https://github.com/rhoeper/Filterpedia-Swift4 You need not do anything except use an iPad. (Remember, it will work in a simulator but about 10x slower.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the comments, but here's the full (and better formatted) answer on how to set up a call to `CIHueAdjust`, using Swift 4:

```
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIHueAdjust")
let context = CIContext()
var extent: CGRect!
var scaleFactor: CGFloat!

@IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let ciImage = CIImage(image: img.image!)

    // Note: you may use kCIInputImageKey for inputImage
    filter?.setValue(ciImage, forKey: "inputImage")
    filter?.setValue(Float(1), forKey: "inputAngle")
    let result = filter?.outputImage

    var image = UIImage(cgImage: context.createCGImage(result!, from: result!.extent)!)
    img.image = image

}
```